# Internal Activity or Service in Android programs?

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, export

In Android programs, can we hide an `Activity` from the outside? Here are parts of `AndroidManifest.xml` from the program of interst.

```
   <activity
        android:name=".ContactsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_details" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PrefsActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_prefs" />

    <provider
        android:name=".data.ContactsProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/contacts_authority"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service android:name=".svc.RESTService" />
```

Using adb tools, I can launch `ContactsActivity`, but cannot do `ContactsDetailActivity` nor `PrefsActivity`. I cannot make start `RESTService` either. For these three activities and service, I got a security exception like:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.enterpriseandroid.restfulcontacts/.ContactDetailActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.enterpriseandroid.restfulcontac
ts/.ContactDetailActivity } from null (pid=22576, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10045
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1761)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:463)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:108)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I thought that declaring an `activity` or a `service` in `AndroidManifest.xml` would mean exporting them. But the error message told that they are not exported ones.

Can you explain what happens here? If you need more information on the code, please let me know.

Always thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring an activity in the manifest is a *requirement* but it does not reveal it to the outside world if you don't apply any filters to it.

Since your activities have no filters, they can only be started from within your app.

As you've found out `.ContactsActivity` can be located as it has a filter applied:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Do we need any intent-filter when we launch an activity explicitly by having an explicit target component name? For launching an activity with implicit intents, the intent-filter should be necessary.

Comment: @user3509406 you need `android.intent.action.MAIN` serves as an entrypoint to your application.